# Problem in adding days / month / year to a given date using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to add days / months / year to a given date and map it to an input field

```
 
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(15);
        d.setMonth(06);
        d.setYear(2011);

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=d;

        d.setDate(d.getDate()+20);

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+="
"+d.getDate()+"/"+d.getMonth()+"/"+d.getYear("YY");
```

this actually prints out

```
Fri Jul 15 2011 12:45:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

4/7/111
```

actually this is wrong.. it should print out 5/7/2011.. i think by default the system takes as "30" days for a month and adds the +20 days.. but actually Jun has 30 days so that result should be 5/7/2011..

any suggestion about what goes wrong in here.. any alternative for this?

Comment: If you thought that this sets the date to `15.06.2011` and then you add 20 days... how in world can the number of days in May have any influence in your calculation?

Comment: sorry i have mentioned it wrong.. Updated it

Comment: NVM = nevermind... meaning I didn't say anything ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first, you have better to use getFullYear to get year as 2011. You did get number from getDate() and add 20. This break Date. You should get long value from getTime(), and add milli-seconds.

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(15);
    d.setMonth(06);
    d.setFullYear(2011);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+=" "+d.getDate()+"/"+d.getMonth()+"/"+d.getFullYear();
    d.setTime(d.getTime()+1000*60*60*24*20);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+=" "+d.getDate()+"/"+d.getMonth()+"/"+d.getFullYear();
</script>
```

Comment: i get the following output  15/6/2011 4/7/2011 ... but this is wrong too.. it should be 15/6/2011 5/7/2011

Comment: @balanv - just add +1 to month, you will understand it correctly.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`i think by default the system takes as "30" days for a month and adds the +20 days.. but actually May has 31 days so that result should be 5/7/2011.`

You are interpreting it a wrong way, `Month` in a `date` starts with `0 - Jan`..
So as per the date entered by you it comes `Jul 15 2011` on the month number `6`.

When you add 20 to date it will be `Aug 04 2011` and you are directly getting month number which is `7 - i.e. Aug` which misleads your calculation. And for the year, yes it is you should `getFullYear`

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) to get your basics correct..

Answer (score 0):

```
>         var d = new Date();
>         d.setDate(15);
>         d.setMonth(06);
>         d.setYear(2011);
```

is equivalent to:

```
  var d = new Date(2011,6,15); // 15 Jul 2011
```

Months are zero based (January = 0, December = 11).

*Date.prototype.getYear* is specified in ECMA-262 ed5 as `Return YearFromTime(LocalTime(t)) − 1900.` so:

```
  alert(d.getYear()); // 111
```

whereas:

```
  alert(d.getFullYear()); // 2011
```